# Getting random error in Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am getting a random error in my Spring project , which is random because it's there sometimes and disappears sometimes.
the error is : `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: "MyDAOIMPL"; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [MyDAOIMPL$2.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

It generally goes away by maven clean compile and install.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: How do you run your project? Do you run it from IDE? Looks like your target compilation folder is getting partially erased when you try to run the application. I guess you use Eclipse, do you? You should always rebuild your project before run.

Comment: hi  Vladimir Vagaytsev, Yes I run it using Eclipse.But I always rebuild before running. My process is : maven clean , maven clean compile, maven install , run on server (which is tomcat).

Comment: You can get interesting race conditions with the Eclipse compiler and the JDK compiler if you are using Maven. This happens because Eclipse is compiling all the time.

Comment: Oh that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For other who are facing the same issue :
I solved this issue by manually deleting the target folder and building the project after that.